# Problems with FlowLayoutPanel inside Panel with AutoSize

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, panel, autosize

I have the following controls hierarchy:

```
Form
  Panel (AutoSize = true, AutoSizeMode = GrowAndShrink, Dock = Top)
    FlowLayoutPanel (AutoSize = true, AutoSizeMode = GrowAndShrink, Dock = Top)
      Control1, Control2, Control3, Control4, ...
    FlowLayoutPanel (AutoSize = true, AutoSizeMode = GrowAndShrink, Dock = Top)
      Control1, Control2, Control3, Control4, ...
```

Here is how it layouts in various sizes:

Fully visible all 8 buttons, but the Panel forgot to shrink

[Fully visible all 8 buttons, but the Panel forgot to shrink http://img534.imageshack.us/img534/3575/panels1.png](http://img534.imageshack.us/img534/3575/panels1.png)

The first FlowLayoutPanel are fully visible, but the second is only half visible, button8 is missing

[The first FlowLayoutPanel are fully visible, but the second is only half visible, button8 is missing http://img301.imageshack.us/img301/5296/panels2.png](http://img301.imageshack.us/img301/5296/panels2.png)

The first FlowLayoutPanel are fully visible, but the second is only half visible, button7 and button8 are missing

[The first FlowLayoutPanel are fully visible, but the second is only half visible, button7 and button8 are missing http://img697.imageshack.us/img697/4644/panels3.png](http://img697.imageshack.us/img697/4644/panels3.png)

The first FlowLayoutPanel are fully visible, but the second is only quarter visible, button 6, button7 and button8 are missing

[The first FlowLayoutPanel are fully visible, but the second is only quarter visible, button 6, button7 and button8 are missing http://img168.imageshack.us/img168/6428/panels4.png](http://img168.imageshack.us/img168/6428/panels4.png)

As you see, i'm not satisfied from this behavior.
Is there something i can do to get all this work?

Comment: I've seen similar problems with FlowLayoutPanel. It seems to be buggy. As _simon_ suggests, you can often (but not always) use TableLayoutPanels to achieve what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like a bug... you could report it to Microsoft.

One possible workaround: try to use tableLayoutPanel instead of your outer panel. Like this:

```
Form
    TableLayoutPanel (1 column, 2 rows with 50% size type)
        FlowLayoutPanel1 (AutoSize = true, in first row of the TableLayoutPanel, Dock = Fill)
            Button1, Button2, Button3, Button4, ...
        FlowLayoutPanel2 (SutoSize = true, in second row of the TableLayoutPanel, Dock = Fill)
            Button1, Button2, Button3, Button4, ...
```

Comment: Thanks! this is working, except the ugly animation on resizing, but it layouts without bugs! :-)